# using paramiko how to add ssh key to ssh-agent for multiple hops

Tags: paramiko

I need to ssh to a remote machine via jumphost.

using ssh i do like this:
ssh -A -t user@jumphost  ssh -A user@vm_to_login

if i just want to run some command, i run: 
ssh -A -t user@jumphost  ssh -A user@vm_to_login "command to execute"

now i tried doing this using python:

```
def ssh_connect(jumphost_ip):
  ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  path_to_key=os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.ssh', 'id_rsa')
  ssh_client.connect(jumphost_ip, username='vagrant', key_filename=path_to_key, allow_agent=True)
  return ssh_client

ssh_client = ssh_connect(host_ip)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command( """ssh montana@vm_to_run_command -A "docker network inspect --format '{{json .Containers }}'  bridge" """, get_pty=True)
```

when i run the above script, the program is hanging for infinite time.. i just guess the SSHClient object is not able to add keys to ssh agent and when the 2nd server looks for keys, the key request go to jumpbox and from jumpbox it some to my local, but SSHClient object does have those keys.

please let me know in case any more information required.

Answer (score 3):

I have got answer on how to handle agent forwarding using paramiko

```
def ssh_connect(jumphost_ip):
  ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  path_to_key=os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.ssh', 'id_rsa')
  ssh_client.connect(jumphost_ip, username='vagrant', key_filename=path_to_key, allow_agent=True)
  s = ssh_client.get_transport().open_session()
  # set up the agent request handler to handle agent requests from the server
  paramiko.agent.AgentRequestHandler(s)
  return ssh_client
```

before using the above program user has to make sure that correct private key is added to ssh-agent. run below command  on host to add private key to ssh-agent:
1. eval $(ssh-agent)
2. ssh-add [path to private key. ex - ~/.ssh/id_rsa]